# Codeigniter $data returns emty

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

Hello guys I have a problem with calling array which is declared in MY_Controller and want to use in Welcome controller. I'm new with ci so I think it's a simple problem or I has forgot something to load in config... (I'm using ci 2.2)

MY_Controller :

> ```
> class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {
>
>   public $data = array();
>
>   function __construct() {
>       parent::__construct();
>       $data['test'] = 'Hello World';          
>   }
>
> }
> ```

Welcome controller >

```
class Welcome extends MY_Controller {
    public function index()
    {
        var_dump($this->data);
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }
}
```

and the result is :

array (size=0)
  empty

Why is my array empty, why not "Hello world"?

Comment: OPP 101 - `$this->data = ['test'=>'hello world']` or `$this->data['test'] = 'Hello world';` Use the `$this` keyword to access objects,methods within the class scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your **MY_Controller constructor** to below:

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller 
{
  function __construct() 
  {
      parent::__construct();
      $this->data = array('test' => 'Hello World');
  }    
}
```

**No need of this:**

```
public $data = array();
```

**Explanation:**

To access the members of the same or parent class you have to use the keyword **`$this`**.

**Example:**

1) To access/declare a variable:

```
$this->variable_name;
```

2) To access a method/function:

```
$this->function_name();
```